# Is it OK to ask for feedback on my personal portfolio?

Tags: discussion, scope, chat

This is one of the most active GIS users platform I am aware of, with a large user base.

I have prepared a personal [portfolio](http://www.cartoskill.com/) for Spatial Data Visualization, showing my skills and projects for which I would like to get some feedback/ suggestions.

GIS and mapping being a comparatively niche area of expertise, it is difficult to find a common platform of experts to ask for feedback/ suggestions. I feel this site as a part of GIS Stack Exchange is one of the best option for the same. However, please feel free to close my question, if it is off topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GIS Stack Exchange [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) would be your best source for getting feedback on your portfolio. The main GIS SE Q & A site would be an inappropriate forum because any answers would be subjective and based entirely on opinion. Alternatively, you can post maps at [Cartotalk](http://www.cartotalk.com/)'s Map Gallery and get feedback from professionals.

Comment: Thanks @Aron. I have accepted your answer. Also I have already posted on cartotalk, that you have suggested. I think I should delete my question, as it is attracting down votes.

Comment: @thelastray There's no need to delete or close your question because it is the first time someone has asked here whether it is OK to ask for feedback about their portfolio at Meta/Main GIS SE.  It was a useful question because it gave Aaron a chance to point out the role of the GIS Chat Room for such questions.  I suspect that the downvotes are just to "say" that Meta is not the place to ask for the feedback.  Voting works different on Meta to Main so there is no need to be at all concerned about a few downvotes here.